# How to Properly Use xargs With cp

Tags: bash, command-line, xargs, cp

What I want to do is read a list of filenames from an index file and then copy each listed file to another directory, but I'm having a little trouble properly stringing xargs and cp together.

```
head -n 150 ../indexes/index.txt | xargs cp ~/path/to/destination/
```

This gives the following error:

```
cp: target 'foo.txt': Not a directory
```

where `foo.txt` is the 150th filename listed in index.txt. Clearly cp should be taking the input from xargs as its first operand and not the second, but how do I get it to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`xargs` has a `-I` parameter, which essentially allows you to specify a substitution pattern and write a substitution pattern in a command (`cp`, in your case). Then, when the command is executed, all instances of that substitution pattern are replaced with the next line of input. So, your command string should look something like this:

```
head -n 150 ../indexes/index.txt | xargs -I {} cp {} ~/path/to/destination/
```

Without the `-I`, `cp` just sees the second line of input as the destination, which is not what's intended.

**Update:** So, a breakdown of what's happening:
As each line of input is read from `head`, since you've set up a pipe, the output of `head` goes to the pipe. When `xargs` gets a new line from the pipe, because you've specified  `... -I {} cp {} ...`, instead of trying to create one large argument string composed of each line of input and trying to pass that to `cp`, it executes `cp` using each line of input as the source operand.

To explain a little further, consider this scenario. We have a file called `test.txt` that contains the following:

```
some_file.txt
another_file.txt
a_third_file.txt
```

Now, suppose we want to write a command to copy all of those files to a given destination. If we simply write...

```
cat test.txt | xargs cp /path/to/destination
```

...then what `cp` effectively sees is this:

```
cp some_file.txt another_file.txt a_third_file.txt
```

In this form, it tries to treat `a_third_file.txt` as a directory and copy the previous two files to it (which is why in your case `cp` says the 150th path is not a directory). `xargs -I {}` fixes that:

```
cat test.txt | xargs -I {} cp {} ~/path/to/destination
```

Now, instead of `cp` only being executed once, `cp` gets executed three times:

```
cp some_file.txt ~/path/to/destination
cp another_file.txt ~/path/to/destination
cp a_third_file.txt ~/path/to/destination
```

Comment: @Luca Sorry about that; was writing things in passing. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Tangentiall maybe avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: @tripleee Slightly, but that's something I'd never considered. I'll definitely keep that in mind for shell scripting going forward.

Answer (score 3):

If using the GNU version of `cp`, it has a `-t directory` option to specify the destination to copy all the filenames given to, instead of having that be the last argument:

```sh
head -n 150 ../indexes/index.txt | xargs cp -t ~/path/to/destination/
```

Comment: You should add options to handle filenames with spaces correctly, i.e. use `head -z -n 150 ../indexes/index.txt | xargs -0 cp -t ~/path/to/destination`. Already submitted an edit proposal.

Comment: @ŁukaszRajchel That only works if the file contains 0-separated records to start.

Comment: (Being able to robustly handle filenames with spaces, newlines, etc. is a worthy goal, but difficult here. It's too bad `xargs` doesn't have an option to split just on newlines, not all whitespace, which would cover many such cases (But not newlines in the names, of course)).